# Tabulator.js - doesn't seem possible to hide column group initially

Tags: tabulator

I have a tabulator table displaying a set of grouped columns.

I would like to have some of the groups hidden by default, so I add visible: false to the group definition

```
{ title: "A group", headerTooltip: "Data relevant to group", visible: false,
    columns: [
        { title: "blah",         field: "blah",  },
    ],
},
```

But the column group is displayed when the table loads.

When I hide/unhide the column group from javascript I can see the visible flag toggle between true and false.

Any advice to make this work would be much appreciated.

(Currently I have to hide all of the columns in the group to make the group hidden).

Thanks
Mike

Answer (score 0):

The `visible` option is only available on actual columns not groups, the correct approach is to set all of the actual columns to `visible:false` as you have done above.

A full list of the options available on a column group can be found in the [Column Grouping Docs](https://tabulator.info/docs/5.4/columns#groups)